# Does a 400ms Wall Time vs a 13ms CPU Time mean I can consider this lambda function non-blocking?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am calling a lambda function via boto3 on a Flask API using `InvocationType="Event"` so it calls asynchronously:

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

And I am invoking the call with something like:

```
response = client.invoke(FunctionName='testFunc',
                         InvocationType='Event',
                         Payload='abc')
```

And using ipython's %time magic function to evalute performance.

It has a readout like this:

```
CPU times: user 13 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 13 ms
Wall time: 406 ms
```

**I am wondering, is this going to block the api at all?**  Since it only takes 13 ms, should I be concerned with the duration of the request or should I consider this non-blocking?  I'm just concerned the 400ms could be considered a slowdown and whether or not I should consider threading this so the user doesn't have to wait for a response from this action. The point of using lambda is to avoid using Celery, so if it's going to still take 400ms I'm curious what benefits I get from using this external service.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke

Comment: How do you measure? What's exactly the code you use to invoke?

Comment: Invoke it more than once with the same client object. Part of the wall clock time is probably the time to set up the initial SSL connection, making the first request slower than subsequent requests occurring within a relatively short time interval.  If you are testing from a machine outside of AWS, test it inside.